# Database Crash on Aggregated Queries in CnosDB

Tags: sql, cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

I am experiencing an issue with CnosDB when running aggregated queries over a large dataset. This is observed while testing a proof of concept involving real-time sensor data injection.

The database crashes when executing aggregated queries over a long time period. Short duration queries work as expected. The crash results in the Docker container stopping.

**Logs:**
The following are the last outputs from the log before the crash:

```
2023-11-29T07:02:47.003237599Z INFO meta::service::single: watch notify watch.1001 45024.45024
2023-11-29T07:02:47.003462338Z INFO meta::service::single: watch all args: client-id: watch.1001, cluster: cluster_xxx, tenants: {"cnosdb"}, version: 45025
2023-11-29T07:02:47.008544790Z INFO meta::service::single: watch notify watch.1001 45025.45025
2023-11-29T07:02:47.008720439Z INFO meta::service::single: watch all args: client-id: watch.1001, cluster: cluster_xxx, tenants: {"cnosdb"}, version: 45026
```

#### To Reproduce

**Example of Working Query (Short Duration):**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT soft_sensor, MAX(time), MIN(time)
FROM "factory_n"
WHERE physical_sensor = 'Sensor1'
AND time > NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minutes'
GROUP BY soft_sensor
```

The query above is just an example of working query. This is working because I have `WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minutes'`. Below is the queries that are failing.

**Failing Query (Long Duration):**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT soft_sensor, MAX(time), MIN(time)
FROM "factory_n"
WHERE physical_sensor = 'Sensor1'
GROUP BY soft_sensor
```

This query causes the database to crash. In Grafana, the query runs for a while before returning a timeout error.

**Error Message:**
`Post "http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?db=public": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

**Additional Failing Query Example:**

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "factory_n"
WHERE physical_sensor = 'Sensor1'
```

#### Expected behavior

The database should be able to handle long-duration aggregated queries without crashing.

#### Additional context

CnosDB version: docker image: cnosdb/cnosdb:community-2023-11-27 (i have tried with older also)
Deployment: Docker container
Docker command: command: ["cnosdb", "run", "-M", "singleton"]
Dataset: Data from 50 locations, each with 50 physical sensors (referred to as physical_sensor in queries). Each physical sensor reports 8 soft-sensor values (referred to as soft_sensor in queries) every second. This means total injections: 20.000 sensor values for each second. This has been running for about 8 days